# Extracting columns having values >= 90%

Tags: python

I wrote this script to extract values from my .txt file that have >= 90 % identity. However, this program does not take into consideration values higher than 100.00 for example 100.05, why?

```
import re
output=open('result.txt','w')
f=open('file.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line.strip())
    id_per=new_list[2]
    if id_per >= '90': 
        new_list.append(id_per)
        output.writelines(line)
f.close()
output.close()
```

Input file example

```
A   99.12
B   93.45
C   100.00
D   100.05
E   87.5
```

Comment: `and id_per <= 100`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compare them as `floats` not `strings`. Something as follows:

```
import re
output=open('result.txt','w')
f=open('file.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line.strip())
    id_per=new_list[2]
    if float(id_per) >= 90.0: 
        new_list.append(id_per)
        output.writelines(line)
f.close()
output.close()
```

This is because python compares is interpreting the `numbers` as `strings` even though you want them interpreted as `numbers`. For `strings`, python does the comparisons character by character  using the `ASCII` or `Unicode` rules. This is why your code will not throw any error however it will not run the way you expect it to run using `float` rules rather than `string` rules.

Comment: it says ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '99.12'. I used float(id_per) instead of int(id_per), do you think it is OK?

Comment: @user3224522, Ah yes, they are floats. Yes you should be fine.

Comment: @user3224522, Sorry for that hiccup, I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @sshashank124's answer, you could use simple string manipulation if your lines have a simple format;

```
output=open('result.txt','w')
f=open('file.txt','r')
for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    num_per=words[1]
    if float(num_per) >= 90: 
        new_list.append(num_per)
        output.writelines(line)
f.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is dynamicaly but **strongly** typed language. Therefore `90` and `'90'` are completely different things - one is integer number and other is a string.

You're comparing *strings* and in string comparison, `'90'` is "greater" than `'100.05'` (strings are compared characted by character and `'9'` is greater than `'1'`).
So what you need to do is:

1. convert `id_per` to number (you'll want probably floats, as you care about decimal places)
2. compare it to **number**, i.e., `90`, not a `'90'`

In code:

```
id_per = float(new_list[2])
if id_per >= 90:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using string comparison - lexically 100 is less than 90. I bet that it works for 950...

Get rid of the quotes around the `'90'`